# (C++) Seperate Numbers within a string which are separated by spaces

Tags: visual-c++

so the part of my programme I'm having an issue is that I need the user to input a series of numbers (the amount is up to them) with each number separated by a space, at the end they have to put in the letter 'e' to indicate that they have finished inputting numbers. The only way to incorporate the 'e' into it is to make the input string and separate the characters by determining the spaces within the string and then placing said numbers into a vector. I managed to get it to work with a char but it then makes any number they input 1 digit.

```
Check = true;
cout << "Please enter data (0 - 25) with spaces followed by the letter 'e'.\n";
bool Error = false;
VectorSize = 0;
Data.resize(VectorSize);
int i = 0;
while (Error == false)
{
    cin >> CTemp;
    switch (CTemp)
    {
    case 'e':
        if (VectorSize != 0)
        {
            Error = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Please enter at least one value before 'e'";
            Check = false;
            break;
        }
    default:
        Temp = CTemp - 48;
        cout << Temp << endl;
        VectorSize++;
        Data.resize(VectorSize);
        if ((Temp > 25) || (Temp < 0))
        {
            Data[i].InputData(rand() % 26);
        }
        else
        {
            Data[i].InputData(Temp);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
return Check;
```

The above code is the version using char. I need help implementing string into it.

Comment: If you can use a `CString`, its `Tokenize` function can be useful to you. And I don't see any utility for the ending 'e'.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information to figure out what's `InputData`, `VectorSize`, etc. in your code. But if I understand the question right, you need to tokenize using space as delimiter. Something like this should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> vec;
    stringstream st("1 3 5 12 48 38 38 94 e");
    string temp;

    while(st >> temp)
        vec.push_back(temp);

    vec.pop_back(); //remove the 'e'

    for(auto s:vec)
        cout<<s<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this code is not validating the input (for instance, we don't know if the last entry was in fact 'e').

Comment: Ok thats a big step in the right direction. How would I allow the user to choose the string that's within the ss stringstream and how would I convert each of the output (s) to int.

Comment: @ Vada Poche  I have managed to convert the numbers into int so thats not a problems anymore. Im still having trouble how to figure out how to allow the user to input the numbers (i.e. the ones you created within the stringstream)

Comment: @Alex You could read your input into a string and initialize the stream with it. Something like this: `#include<sstream> 
    int main()
    {
        string s;
        getline(cin, s);
        std::stringstream ss(s);
        //cout << endl << ss.str() << endl;
        return 0;
    }`

Comment: If the answer was helpful (only if it was), I'd appreciate if you could mark it as such.